# How can I use typed variables as types with same name in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

When using [`THREE.js`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) along with Typescript, you can use the same names for types and code. For example:

```js
import * as THREE from '/build/three.module.js'

// Following line uses THREE.Scene as type and code
const scene: THREE.Scene = new THREE.Scene()
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Sean-Bradley/Three.js-TypeScript-Boilerplate/tree/statsgui/?file=/src/client/client.ts:197-241)

Im **trying to replicate the same behaviour** in my own code, but In not sure how to do it.
This is what Ive tried:

```js
// typedModule.ts

export const typedConstant1: string = "string";

// Doesnt work
// declare global {
//     namespace typedModule {
//       export type typedConstant1 = typeof typedConstant1
//     }
//   }
```

```js
// index.ts

import * as typedModule from "./typedModule";

const someVariable: typedModule.typedConstant1 = typedModule.typedConstant1; // ERROR: Namespace '"/sandbox/src/typedModule"' has no exported member 'typedConstant1'.ts(2694)
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-microservice-x1732?file=/src/index.ts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to export types the same way you export values:

```
export const typedConstant1: string = "string";
export type typedConstant1 = typeof typedConstant1;
```

and then importing should work:

```
import * as typedModule from "./typedModule";

const someVariable: typedModule.typedConstant1 = typedModule.typedConstant1;
// const someVariable: string
```

[Modified codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-lewin-epky6)

[Similar code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAXAnjCATAsgeywFcAbZAbwCgkkIAPGPAJxSXj2ChfUywGF3OIYCgCMALiSdGAS2ABzJAF4kAIimy5KgNxUa9JlwzJu2fhxRDRS1EbwAzGzzODhInQF8KXtucl5IAGogMiAARqQSJrgEJBAAdFHOFq7WUfhEpAlGfALJojoA9AWsuX6BwdJhEZIoMvJeUP4QQSHh8Sh4AKowmIy8IFAQABQAlFpIRUh4ANYgaEA)